# Inequality to denote the probability of a single point

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In my notes, the probability of a single point is denoted  as $P(X=a)=P(\{a\})= lim_{\epsilon \to \ 0^+}P(a- \epsilon<X\leq a)$. Is this inequality right?

Because I think that at the limit, this inequality becomes $P(a<X\leq a)$, or $P(a<a)$.

Comment: Yes: $t\mapsto P(t<X\le a)$ is not necessarily continuous.

Comment: In your last sentence; recall that taking the limit does not preserve strict inequalities. A trivial example to keep in mind is that, when $x\to 0^+$, we have $x>0$ at every value, but $0=\lim_{x\to 0^+} x \geq 0$ (not a strict inequality, of course).

Comment: In the context of this problem, Lord Shark's "yes" refers to what you wrote in your first sentence, but not to your last sentence.

Comment: "$0=\lim_{x\to 0^+}$". Then if strict inequalities are not preserved when taking the limit, why isn't denoted as $P(\{a\})= lim_{\epsilon \to \ 0^+}P(a- \epsilon \leq X\leq a)$ instead?. The limit in this case is $a$.

Comment: I don't see a strong reason for preferring $<$ over $\leq$ here, except use and convenience (someone, please chime in if I'm missing something). Namely, if you denote the cdf of $X$ as $F$ (which is right-continuous and has left-limits everywhere), then the above expression becomes $F(a)-F(a_-) = F(a) - \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} F(a-\varepsilon)$.